# How to use Kotlin Flows to poll resource and emit it?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I want to make a nice logic for forever looping and emitting results with Kotlin Flows. The use case is that every n minutes I need to update a configuration in my app and this configuration comes from a rest api.

I thought a nice solution would be to run a "scheduler" that polls the api every n minutes in the background, and a `ConfigService` which is subscribed to this scheduler can update it's own state when the scheduler emits a new value.

Using RxJava this would be

```
Observable.interval(n, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .flatMap( ... )
```

But since I am using Kotlin I thought I could implement the same logic with the native Flow library. How would that look like? I was trying to google and either did not find the right keywords or just no one run into the same issue before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you use flow builder function, call suspending function to fetch the data and `emit` the result

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlin.time.minutes

flow<ApiResult> {
  while (true) {
    emit(fetchApi())
    delay(10.minutes)
  }
}
```

Be aware that this implementation is cold - i.e. it stops when it is not collected/observed.

It is possible that in the future there will be something like [tickerFlow](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/1908). The old [ticker](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/ticker.html) for channels (possibly converted to flow) is deprecated and definitely should not be used.

Comment: I was doing this, but is this the best we can do atm?

Comment: AFAIK yes, or of course you may create own ticker functions returning flow and (flat)map on it.

Comment: Wouldn't this possible to acts as DDOS instead in server (if the user is million or billion)? @hrach

Comment: It depends. If you have milion or bilion users, your backend servers is well scaled and is able to handle such amount request. Second, it depends how often you want to refresh. You may also deploy other strategies like web-sockets or push-notifications to allow user refresh when something happens and do not poll.

Comment: How do you handle exceptions and no network connectivity when trying to `fetchApi()`? so the polling can resume once network is back or if the Exception is a Timeout for instance.